# Python asyncio non-blocking wait after return

Tags: python, api, python-asyncio

I created API on Python and i want to start some long function, but I want to tell user that my endpoint worked successfully and i some task started in execution
I want to do it because i want so that the user does not wait for the function to be executed

If it were represented in pseudocode, it would probably look like this:

async my_endpoint(context):
func_name = context.func_name

<something_validation_block>
return 204 if all right

So, how created in one function ?

I tried something as:

```
async def handle(context):
    
<validate_block>
threading.Thread(
    target=logn_func, args=(context,),
).start()
return 204
```

But unfortunately it does not work : (

Answer (score 0):

First, asyncio has a method named `asyncio.to_thread` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)
It's provide a friendly method to work with async and threading.

(Or you can run task in threading pool [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_exe#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools))

then, you can use `asyncio.create_task(coro)` to run async function in background
it will return a `Task` object which is awaitable, or use `task.add_done_callback` to handle result.

```
import asyncio
import time


def block() -> str:
    print("block function start")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("block function done")
    return "result"


async def main() -> int:
    task = asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, block)
    task.add_done_callback(lambda task: print("task with result:", task.result()))
    print("return 204")
    return 204


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
block function start
return 204
block function done
task with result: result
```

NOTE: Save a reference to tasks, to avoid a task disappearing mid-execution. The event loop only keeps weak references to tasks. A task that isn’t referenced elsewhere may get garbage collected at any time, even before it’s done.